# phpDocumentor directory does not exist

Tags: phpdoc

Im trying to run phpDocumentor on a new server with the following command:

```
phpdoc -d /var/www/vhosts/mysite.com/httpdocs/source -t /var/www/vhosts/mysite.com/httpdocs/docs
```

But it always says:

```
[InvalidArgumentException]                                                                     
The "/var/www/vhosts/mysite.com/httpdocs/source" directory does not exist.
```

I give 777 permissions to source and docs folder, but that doesn't work.